# When does Protractor throw 'unknown error: cannot determine loading status'..... exception

Tags: selenium, protractor, chrome-web-driver

Can anyone tell me when does Protractor throw 
**'unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Internal error: main world execution context not found."}'** exception.

I understand that "Unknown Error" is thrown from WireProtocol and it generally means application returned 4xx or 5xx status code. But not sure what "**Internal error: main world execution context not found.**" means

Thanks in advance!

Conf.js

```
exports.config = {
        framework: 'jasmine',
        allScriptsTimeout: 600000,
        onPrepare: function () {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(600000);
            require('jasmine-reporters');
            var jReporter=new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(__dirname + '\\Logs', true, true, undefined, true);
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(jReporter);
        },
        rootElement: 'body',
        chromeDriver: 'C:/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe',
        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': {'debuggerAddress': 'localhost:8088'}
        },
        jasmineNodeOpts: {
            isVerbose: true,
            showColors: true,
            includeStackTrace: true,
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 900000
        },
        onComplete: function () {},
        onCleanUp: function() { },
        specs: ['./sampleTest.spec.js']             
        };
```

Comment: What protractor version are you using? What if you would try run it without the Chrome Options specified?

Comment: @alecxe protractor version I am using is 1.0.0(Yes,really old; I am asked to use only this version) and when I try without the Chrome option issue is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the driver version that couse the issue.

see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5347

and you can add

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-site-isolation-trials')
```

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-site-isolation-trials')